# Website with Admins that can add/edit articles/pages

Tags: html, web, authentication, admin

Recently, we have launched the website for our Call of Duty clan. However, we would like admins to be able to log in on the page, and allow them to add or edit articles to the homepage or other pages, or edit pages like a member roster.

I'm not expecting very specific answers since this is quite vague i think, but i was wondering what kind of system we should be using for this. I myself have quite some experience with HTML and css, but less with PHP and JS. I can use them, but i don't have the experience to know what system to use for these kind of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easy to answer your question!
I would install Joomla - www.joomla.org. A lot of other clans for Call of Duty use it, and it's really user-friendly to install. (It's also free).

Joomla allows you and other people you choose to upload articles, edit them - all via the Admin section. No programming or PHP experience is necessary.  for install instructions, just search YouTube.com for "Install Joomla".

G'Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The term for what you're looking for is CMS, or Content Management System. There are a hojillion of these out there, and some of them even with free hosting. Here is a directory for php CMS:

http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=1&cat=CMS%20/%20Portals

DotNetNuke is a popular Windows CMS. Here is a site with free DNN hosting:

http://www.dnn4free.com/

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of engines out there. Joomla, Wordpress(blog+), Drupal, and etc. If you are looking to blog a lot I would suggest Wordpress.  Basically these are CMS (content management systems).

Answer (score 0):

It has been mentioned, but I would like to throw in my support for wordpress. Especially if you don't have a ton of experience with web based applications, deployment with most hosting providers is extremely easy.